# In VSCode, how can I highlight each variable of a different color, like with Atom's semanticolor?

Tags: visual-studio-code, themes, syntax-highlighting

My editor of choice is Atom. I'm considering switching to VSCode because everybody is suggesting me to.

In Atom I use [semanticolor](https://atom.io/packages/semanticolor): it colors each variable of a different color and I quite like that.

! [semanticolor screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gBd6W.png) (I don't have enough reputation to post images. Please somebody fix this)

I heard that VSCode started supporting semantic highlighting too. I enabled it, even tried to play with various settings, but didn't manage to achieve the effect of semanticolor.

How can I achieve a similar result?

Comment: I found some large issues on github about semantics highlighting, but I'm not able to fully understand what they're talking about: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/92308

Comment: I miss the days of monospaced/monochrome fonts on a serial VT terminal ;)